# HTTP Request from Button Click in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, web, webforms

I have a button. I want it to submit a http request.

And then redirect it to string + request.absolute.uri.

```
  signInUrl +=  "?Invitation=" + m_invitation;
  Response.Redirect(signInUrl, true);
```

The issue is that now I can't use the request.absolute.uri since it is just a click event even though I have put a runat server tag.

```
<ASP:BUTTON id="SignIn" TabIndex="1" runat="server" OnClick="SignIn_Click"></ASP:BUTTON>
```

How can I do that?

Please help. Thanks.

Comment: why dont you create the uri on click yourself, you can get the other parts using [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: @Rex I can't, I fetch the invitation link from the db once the button is clicked. so i have to use the response.

Comment: do you absolutely have to do postback? If not then you can get away with a javascript click handler attribute like this: ` <ASP:BUTTON id="SignIn" TabIndex="1" runat="server"
   onclientclick="myFunction()"
   runat="server" OnClick="SignIn_Click" /> `

Answer (score 0):

On your aspx.vb supporting page you can create a protected query to handle all of this. You should only put UI in the view page, leaving the actions made by user seperated from that layer. It makes it easier for people coming in after you to edit it. Instead of going back and forth between layers, that is now all handled in one method.

```
Protected Sub BtnSIgnIn_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles SignIn.Click
Me.SignedIn = True
Response.Redirect(Url);
End Sub
```

Answer (score -1):

I would suggest using an asp:LinkButton instead of just asp:Button.

Button does a postback.  LinkButton reloads the page.

Comment: Where did you get this info? It is just not true.